# Tidy Number challenge and 'every' method

Tags: javascript, arrays, methods

I was trying to solve this kata on codewars:

https://www.codewars.com/kata/5a87449ab1710171300000fd/train/javascript

And after I solved it I looked on the solutions where found something like this:

`function tidyNumber(n){
  let arr = [...n.toString()].map(Number);
  return arr.every((el, ind, arr) => !ind || el >= arr[ind - 1]);
}`

Can someone explain to me how exactly this part: **!ind** works ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

first element will give true as ind is 0, and not 0 is true, when index is on second element it checks with the previous. This way you dont check against nothing.